# Как изменить значение в скобках?

Tags: javascript

Например, есть элементы

```
<span class="abc">Текст (х=1)</span>
<span class="abc">Текст (х=0)</span>
```

Если в элементе значение в скобках "х=1", то производить его замену на "y"

```
<span class="abc">Текст (y)</span>
<span class="abc">Текст (х=0)</span>
```

Comment: чистый JS или можно jQuery?

Comment: jQuery можно, буду признателен

Comment: @Acht88, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/hpxv4znp/

**HTML**

```
<span class="abc">Текст (х=1)</span>
<span class="abc">Текст (х=0)</span>
```

**CSS**

```
$('.abc').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.html().replace(/х=1/g, 'y'));
});
```